# Emacs shell (bash) crashes on background pipe command

Tags: bash, emacs

On a Linux system, I start generic Emacs (version 25.2):

`emacs -q`

Then start a shell within a new Emacs window (by default it is `bash`):

`M-x shell`

Then run a pipe command in the background:

`$ ls | cat &`

After printing the normal output, the shell process immediately terminates, showing:

```
$ exit
Process shell finished
```

What could be going wrong?

Note that both `(ls | cat &)` and `(ls | cat) &` do not cause the shell to terminate.

Comment: I cannot reproduce (GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.20) of 2017-09-12, modified by Debian)